# How to get values in against a specific index in a list in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

The issue is i want to perform CRUD in list but its not the sameas doing with enity framework.Kinldy guid me how to perform Get id and perform Edit operation against it same for Detail and add.
   **View**

```
    <table>
               <tr>
               <th>Product name</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
           <th>Unit Price</th>
           <th>Line Total</th>                                                      
           </tr>
 @foreach (var item in Model)
     {
     <tr>
    <td>@item.Product_Name</td>
         <td>@item.SalesOrder_Quantity</td>
            td>@item.Unit_Price</td>
                                <td>@item.SalesOrder_Total</td>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new{ id = Model.ToList().IndexOf(item) }) |
                                    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = Model.ToList().IndexOf(item) }) |
                                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = Model.ToList().IndexOf(item) })
                                </td>
                            </tr>
               }
```

**Controller**

```
 public class CreateSOController : Controller
   {
    Hisaab_ApplicationEntities db = new Hisaab_ApplicationEntities();
    static List<SalesOrddrDetail_ViewMode> row_list = new        List<SalesOrddrDetail_ViewMode>();

    // GET: CreateSO
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(row_list);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Insert(SalesOrddrDetail_ViewMode salesViewModel)
    { 
          row_list.Add(salesViewModel);
          return RedirectToAction("Index",salesViewModel);
    }
         Here i havethe issue
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
         row.list.find(id) it show error here 
        return PartialView();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = Model.ToList().IndexOf(item) })`?

Use it like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = @item.id })
```

Comment: No need for the `@` symbol before `item`

Answer (score 0):

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new{ id = Model.ToList().IndexOf(item) }) |
@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = Model.ToList().IndexOf(item) }) |
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = Model.ToList().IndexOf(item) })
```

This part of your code is incorrect.  There is no need to get the index of the item in the Model, since in the view there is already a `foreach` loop separating out each item.

All you have to do is:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new{ id = item.ID }) |
@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.ID }) |
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.ID })
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: thank you BviLLe_Kid it works for me thanks alto it take around 3 hour but you solved my problem and cleared my concept.

Comment: @AbdullahFaraz please mark an answer as accepted so that this question can be recognized as solved